# Can I capture screen data to a file with gdb version 6.3.50?

Tags: logging, gdb, screen

I would like to be able to capture the output of a user-defined command to a file. Is there a way to turn screen-logging on and off from within gdb?

Comment: Previously I needed to visually scan hundreds of lines of gbd screen data and record some addresses. Then I would feed the addresses to a transform program that would generate a file for gdb to use. This morning I wrote a shell script to parse the gdb log data and pipe it through the transform program. I can run the shell script while still in gdb.

Answer (score 1):

`(gdb) set logging on`

See ["2.4 Logging output"](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html#Logging-Output) in GDB manual.

Comment: As far as I can tell, logging to a file is supported since GDB 6.0